# ASP alternative to codepad.org

Tags: compiler-construction

Is there any alternative to http://codepad.org/ for use with ASP language? I would like to quickly check syntax online.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

How about http://ideone.com/ it supports C# & VB.NET, no mention of ASP specifically though.